# Almost sure convergence of a net

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $X_\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon > 0$ be random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ (or any metric space) defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. Assume that $X_{\varepsilon_n}$ converges to $X$ $P$-almost surely for all sequences $\varepsilon_n \to 0$. Does it follow that $X_\varepsilon$ converges to $X$ $P$-almost surely as $\varepsilon \to 0$?

For real functions on metric spaces continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity. But the issue here is that we have a probability measure in between. Also, the set of all null sequences is uncountable, so we can get measurability issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The trouble is that one can find an uncountable family of disjoint sequences of positive real numbers converging to $0$. If this family is $(\epsilon_n^i)_n, i\in I$ (where $I$ is some uncountable set), then the numbers $\epsilon_n^i$ are all distinct from one another, so the variables $X_{\epsilon_n^i}$ can be defined any way we like, independently of one another. Thus, for fixed $i$, we can make the sequence $X_{\epsilon_n^i}$ fail to converge to $X$ on some negligible set $Z_i$, but such that $\bigcup_{i\in I} Z_i$ is non-negligible. Therefore $X_\epsilon$ will not converge a.e. to $X$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. And we can get sequential convergence of course, as long as we define $X_\epsilon$ correctly for all the other values of $\epsilon$, say $X_\epsilon=X$.

Let's just take $X=0$, and the underlying probability space to be $[0, 1]$. We need a few building blocks to make this construction work:

1. An uncountable family $Z_i$ of negligible sets whose union is non-negligible. Easy, take $Z_i=\{i\}$ for $i\in[0,1]$.
2. Given a negligible set $Z$, a sequence of random variables which converges to $0$ everywhere but on $Z$. Just take $X_n=0$ off of $Z$ and $X_n=1$ on $Z$.
3. An uncountable family of disjoint sequences $\epsilon_n^i$ converging to $0$. We can take $\epsilon_n^i=i\frac1n + (1-i)\frac1{n-1}$ for $i\in[0, 1)$, say.

Just for fun, we can write down an explicit formula for the variable $X_x$, $x\in[0, 1)$, all defined on the probability space $[0, 1)$. We would have $X_x(y)=1$ for $y=\frac{x-\frac1{\lceil x\rceil-1}}{\frac1{\lceil x\rceil}-\frac1{\lceil x\rceil-1}}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. Your example is enlightening (I think you have to replace every $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ in $y = \dots$).
I now also found out that [Silvestrov, "Limit Theorems for Randomly Stopped Processes" (2002), p. 20] distinguishes between "almost sure convergence as $\varepsilon \to 0$" (meaning that $P(\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} X_\varepsilon= X) = 1$)
and the weaker property "sub-sequential almost sure convergence as $\varepsilon\to 0$" (meaning that $P(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{\varepsilon_n} = X)$ for all sequences $\varepsilon_n \to 0$.

Comment: However, the Skorokhod representation theorem seems to be valid for $\varepsilon$-nets
[Silvestrov, Theorem 1.3.6] and so we can conclude that if $X_\varepsilon \to X$ subsequentially a.s.
then there exists another probability space and random elements $Y_\varepsilon$ and $Y$ defined there such that $Y_\varepsilon$ is equal in distribution to $X_\varepsilon$, $Y$ is equal in distribution to $X$ and $Y_\varepsilon \to Y$ almost surely.

Comment: In more detail: If $X_{\varepsilon_n} \to X$ a.s. as $n \to \infty$ for all null sequences $\varepsilon_n$ then $X_{\varepsilon_n} \to X$ in distribution for all null sequences $\varepsilon_n$. By [Silvestrov, Theorem 1.3.3] it follows that $X_{\varepsilon} \to X$ in distribution as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Then we can apply the Skorokhod representaion theorem for $\varepsilon$-nets.

Comment: So, for your example, one can define $Y_x(y) := 0$ for all $x$ and $y$ defined on $[0,1)$ with the Lebesgue measure. Then $Y_x$ is equal in distribution to $X_x$ for all $x \in [0,1)$ and $Y_x \to 0 = Y_0$ almost surely as $x \to 0$.